# Pro and Cons Chart Control for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, charts, asp.net-mvc-5

This topic might be opinionated. If it is so, apology. I need to assess the below questions:

1. Should I use ASP.NET MVC controller to generate chart and return the image to the client side?
   If this approach is chosen, is there any reliable free MVC chart control that I could use?
2. Should I use Client Side charting control to generate chart and return the JSON data to be consumed by the client side?
   If I go along using this approach, how to secure the data consume by the client side? I want to prevent the plain data is being copied over or read by simply view source feature of the browser.

Thanks!

Comment: Data on client side never are "secure". So if you do not wish use to copy your plain data in json, probably, you should generate charts server side.

Comment: Client-side isn't secure. You must generate charts server-side and return them as an image. http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/093009-1.aspx, http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/built-in-charting-controls-vs-2010-and-net-4-series

Comment: Thanks for your info. However, I plan to use ASP.NET MVC instead of ASP.NET Webforms. So is there any awesome free chart control of ASP.NET MVC that I could use?

Or, I should have used the paid one?

Comment: Dont apologize.Instead you could try not posting it in the first place.  At 700 rep you should know by now that "Should I .. ?" questions are nearly always offtopic.

Comment: @Hatjhie you can use the chart control in mvc too. http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092210-1.aspx . Look at further reading section.

Comment: Have you tried chartjs? What are your security concerns about using a client side library?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I didn't try this in ASP.NET MVC > 3, but probably works fine.

As a follow-up for my comments. If you need just: Bar Chart, Pie Chart, Column Chart, you can use ASP.NET Web Helpers Library https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers/.

In your controller you'll have an action 'DrawChart' or something like this (for PNG format) :

```
 public ActionResult DrawChart()
        {
            var chart = new Chart(width: 300, height: 200)
                .AddSeries(
                            chartType: "bar",
                            xValue: new[] { "10 Records", "20 Records", "30 Records", "40 Records" },
                            yValues: new[] { "50", "60", "78", "80" })
                            .GetBytes("png");
            return File(chart, "image/bytes");
        }
```

And view : `<img src="@Url.Action("DrawChart")" alt="Drawing chart with HTML Helper" />`

An example here : http://weblogs.asp.net/jalpeshpvadgama/chart-helpers-in-asp-net-mvc3

Answer (score 0):

Give a look at this [library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Chart.Mvc/).

It uses a Canvas control (instead of PNG), giving you interactivity and animation.
The data are generate server-side (so you don't need to expose your datasource) and pass it to chartJS, an open source library that draws the graph.